# Error using theme.breakpoints.down('') from Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm a beginner and I'm using material UI on the front-end, and I'm trying to make my app responsive by using the theme.breakpoints.down according to docs in material UI, but it returns an error :

[theme.breakpoints.down()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSBww.png)

and that's my code :

```
const useStyle = makeStyles({
root : {
    height:"100vh",
    display:"flex",
    justifyContent:"space-evenly",
    alignItems:"center",
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]:{
        flexDirection:"column"
    }
}
```

})

I would like to understand whats going on, and if possible, what could be done to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

makeStyles is a function and return hook , so you can pass "theme" as parameter

so it should be like this :

```
const useStyle = makeStyles((theme)=>({
root : {
    height:"100vh",
    display:"flex",
    justifyContent:"space-evenly",
    alignItems:"center",
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]:{
        flexDirection:"column"
    }
}}))
```